# Managing managers in a Singleton class

Tags: design-patterns, static, singleton

I'm trying to get this straight and to see if my idea is correct or not.

I'm having a few Manager classes. For example, an UserManager and a PhoneManager.

Because I'm having quite a few problems with making all those Manager's static, I was wondering if I could solve it with a 'ManagerManager'.

That ManagerManager would be static, and on creation, it would instantiate all the other Manager's. Because this singleton would be the only one creating the instances, that would also mean all calls through the ManagerManager would end up in the same instance of a Manager. But, with the advantages of the class not being static.

Does this work? Suggestions to improve are welcome as well.

Comment: What's your problem with static classes? It could be interesting, which language your talking about.

Comment: I hope this is a joke that was posted 18 days late.

Comment: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?joel.3.219431.12

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes it's a fair question. I've done stuff like this when I was starting out programming in managed languages.

Comment: It's Friday, I'm allowed to post this kind of crap!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who's going to manage the `ManagerManager`?

Seriously though, `XManager` is often bad design. Rather than a `UserManager`, why not have a `user` object, an `admin` user, a `inactive` user and so forth?

Manager objects become dumping grounds for everything related to `X`. The fact you are using static managers only makes this worse. What about when you have different types of user, or phones? You're stuck with one instance. Break the objects down into smaller, more focused objects and the need for the `ManagerManager` will disappear.

So to answer your question, which is hard without more context/code you should not try this approach. Instead try and refactor your existing code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to think about it. The Manager's aren't really that big and expanded classes. I only created them to avoid having a huge DataManager and split up object-related methods and lists in convienent classes. Seems like splitting it all up was a bad idea for me.

Comment: @Joetjah splitting your code up sounds just fine. A generic DataManager would be the route I would try to avoid. It might be worth checking out and reading up about the SOLID principles, primarily the Single Responsibility Principle at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: The thing you linked is the thing I tried to achieve. Then I guess I'll try to create static managers and see from there how everything works after all.

Comment: Again, without context it's hard to comment too much but I would try to avoid static managers (static code even) - you're fixing yourself in to too much of rigid solution otherwise. Even if you only need one instance now, you might need more in the future. And if you are only making them static so you can instantiate them easier, it sounds as if the configuration of your app (where you instantiate the objects) needs changing. Just push the creation of these objects higher up the dependency chain (closer to main) and the need for statics is gone.